# Wk* continuity and wk* sequential continuity on $S'$

Tags: functional-analysis, schwartz-space

Let $S$ be the Schwartz space and $S'$ be its dual space. If a linear operator $T:S'\rightarrow S'$ is weakly* sequentially continuous, is it also weakly* continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since boundedness is determined by sequences, $T$ maps bounded (= equicontinuous) sets of $S'$ to bounded sets. Since *the* Schwartz space $S$ is *a* Frechet-Schwartz space (i.e., a projective limit of Banach spaces with compact linking maps), either by results of Grothendieck or a theorem of Laurent Schwartz, $S'$ endowed with the strong topology $\beta(S',S)$ (of uniform convergence on bounded subsets of $S$) is bornological and hence $T$ is continuous as a map on $(S',\beta(S',S))$. Then, the transposed $T^t$ is a continuous map on $S''=S$ (Frechet-Schwartz spaces are reflexive) and thus, $T=T^{tt}$ is weak$^*$-continuous on $S$.